# System of Equations ~ Numerical Analaysis

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations

[image]

[image]

The second image is what I've done so far, what do you think? I have no idea how to do part c, any ideas?

Comment: Your next step is to write out the discretized versions of the derivatives. Do you know how to do that? Once you have done that, you plug that and the $p_i,q_i,f_i$ into the differential equation, for $i=1,2,3$. That gives three equations of your system. The remaining two are the boundary equations $y_0=2.3$ and $y_4=3.8$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response.  I'm not really sure how to do that, can you tell me how to write the versions?

Comment: The forward difference approximation to the first derivative is $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$. The centered difference approximation to the second derivative is $\frac{f(x+h)-2f(x)+f(x-h)}{h^2}$. Other options exist; for example, there is a centered difference approximation to the first derivative, which is typically more accurate than the forward difference. But all of these options look similar.